# How can I Insert data into mySQL using VBNet textbox with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

How can i insert data into mysql using the textbox with where clause. here is my code

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into faq (status) values('" & txtBad.Text & "') WHERE due_date <= NOW();"
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. You have a sql statement, do you not know how to execute it now? And you shouldn't use the text from textbox directly, use parameter instead.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `WHERE` clause? A `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT..VALUES` statement makes no sense.

Comment: Consult a decent SQL reference such as http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/ . Do lots of research, then get back to us when you get stuck.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to update the value ,instead of inserting it into table.

in case of update you can use below snippet

```
cmd.CommandText = "update faq set status ='" &  txtBad.Text & "' WHERE due_date <= NOW();"
```

Comment: This is wide open to SQL injection as is the OP's question. A complete answer should point that out.